# Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props file missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, visual-c++-2019

A few days ago, I set up a Windows 10 by clean installation and then installed Visual Studio 2019 Community on it.

Now, I want to customize `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props` and `Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user.props` files to add additional include paths for all my VC++ projects.

But I can't find these files on my brand-new machine.
They should be located at `%localappdata%\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0`, but there is no `MSBuild` directory.

Does it mean that the installation of Visual Studio failed, or do I need some additional procedures to create default *.user.props files?
I've confirmed that the VC++ can build a simple hello-world project.

Edit: Attached a screenshot of the Property Manager. There is no user property sheet.

[image: Property Manager]

Comment: Open the sample c++ project that works, select View / Other Windows / Properties Manager from the menu, then look under <project>\<config>\microsoft.cpp.win32.user to confirm the Property Sheet File location.

Comment: @dxiv I've attached the screenshot of the Property Manager. There is no Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user property sheet.

Comment: Apparently that's "by design". I have those files on my machine, but I have multiple versions of VS installed side by side so they were probably installed by an older version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Microsoft, VS 2019 no longer creates the `.props` files by default.

From [Cannot see Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user in Property Manager](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/502548/cannot-see-microsoftcppwin32user-in-property-manag.html):

> The behavior is intended. Visual Studio 2019 will not create .user files anymore. But if .user files already exist, projects will automatically import them.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Ok, I'll import the user.props files from my previous computer.