How to globally add Boost library paths in Visual Studio for multiple solutions and projects?
I downloaded a C++ project from GitHub that uses Visual Studio. The main solution file, all.sln, contains several solutions, and each solution includes multiple projects. Some of these projects require the Boost library.
I have already built Boost and placed it in D:\\Github\\boost_1_70_0.
Is there a way to register the Boost library's header and library paths globally in Visual Studio 2019/2022, so that I don't have to manually add the Boost header and library paths to each project individually?
I want to be able to include Boost headers like this without additional configuration:
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
How to achieve this?
I tried in 2019 and 2022.

This question looks similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61594646/microsoft-cpp-win32-user-props-file-missing
